# How can I solve this error in logstash run?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

How can I solve this error in logstash run?

Multiple multi-tables succeeded before xpack functionality was set.

But the moment you use the xpack feature,
When running logstash, infinite loading occurs, and the following error occurs.
Below is the `conf file` that I set.

`my conf.file`

```
 input {
        jdbc {
            clean_run => true
            jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar"
            jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql:localhost:3306/db_name?useSSL=false&user=root&password=1234"
            jdbc_user => "root"
            jdbc_password => "1234"
            schedule => "* * * * * Asia/Seoul"
            statement => "select * from access_token"
            type => "access_token"
            tracking_column => "table_1"
            use_column_value => true
            }
    
    
        jdbc {
            clean_run => true
            jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar"
            jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useSSL=false&user=root&password=1234"
            jdbc_user => "root"
            jdbc_password => "1234"
            schedule => "* * * * * Asia/Seoul"
            statement => "select * from activity"
            type => "activity"
            tracking_column => "table_2"
            use_column_value => true
            }
    }
    
    
    output {
        if[type] == "access_token"  {
            elasticsearch {
                hosts => "20.194.48.93:9200"
                index => "0601_test"
                user => "test12"
                password => "test12"
                }
        }
        if[type] == "activity"  {
            elasticsearch {
                hosts => "20.194.48.93:9200"
                index => "0601_test"
                user => "test12"
                password => "test12"
                }
        }
        stdout {
            #codec => rubydebug
            codec => dots {}
        }
    }
```

`i try method`

```
1. /etc/mysql/my.cnf 
--> bind-address : 0.0.0.0
```

[Solving a "communications link failure" with JDBC and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql)

`run error message1`

```
[2021-06-01T03:26:11,050][ERROR][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main][142fbace6ae65011ebe067271d245f5f1dc5f6f9a443f157c6fa6dfae765ea4b] Unable to connect to database. Tried 1 times {:message=>"Java::ComMysqlCjJdbcExceptions::CommunicationsException: Communications link failure\n\nThe last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.", :exception=>Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError, :cause=>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

`run error message2`

```
{ 2066 rufus-scheduler intercepted an error:
  2066   job:
  2066     Rufus::Scheduler::CronJob "* * * * * Asia/Seoul" {}
  2066   error:
  2066     2066
  2066     Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError
  2066     Java::ComMysqlCjJdbcExceptions::CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

`run error message3`

```
[2021-06-01T03:26:11,011][ERROR][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main][0616737e1371528e603f2505cd0592b90ebecf4b855d15d987de4e71e468e748]
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I have `set the xpack function` on elk.
By using the xpack feature,

> How can I solve this error in logstash run?

help me plz.